# How to get url from selenium test class in java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get url(`baseUrl = "http://google.com";`) that is declared in selenium test class from my java class.how can i get the url

is there any selenium api class. Please suggest me

```
public class SeleJunit {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSeleJunit1() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("name")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("i18n2");
    driver.findElement(By.name("mode")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ok-button")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("_.compressionLevel"))).selectByVisibleText("System Default");
    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]
    driver.findElement(By.id("side-panel")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("yui-gen30-button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Jenkins")).click();
  }
```

Comment: do you want to print the current URL?

Comment: yes.but, in some other class i want to get or print the url

Comment: some other class in the sense?

Answer (score 4):

The [`driver.getCurrentUrl()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getCurrentUrl%28%29) method will give you what you want. It'll return the full URL (like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=selenium)), so you'll need to chop the string off after the .com.

Comment: Above i added my selenium test class code.In that i declared a url(baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";).i want to get that url to my new java class.How can i get the URL.If i use driver.getCurrentUrl in my class i am just getting empty(no url)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you mean that you have a separate class to `SeleJunit` (called `OtherClass`, for the sake of example), and you want to get the current URL in a method of `OtherClass`?

Comment: seperate class but not the test class. this seperate class will take the selenium test class as input and need to display the url for which the test class has been written.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Add an accessor method for `baseUrl` to your `SeleJunit` class. Then in `OtherClass`, you can write something like `testUrl = test.getBaseUrl()`. You could also make `baseUrl` public and write `testUrl = test.baseUrl` instead.

Comment: I should not make any changes on test class.My goal is to find the missing selenium test case based on url. first i got the list of urls for a single main url(like google.com) using jsoup. Now i need to get the urls from the selenium test programatically and compare these urls to check whether testcase for that particular url exist or not.

Comment: I might have suggested writing all of this in the original question, since `driver.getCurrentUrl()` wouldn't be very appropriate for what you're actually trying to do! In any case, I'm not sure there's a way to do this without editing `SeleJunit` in some way; you need access to that `baseUrl` variable.

Answer (score 0):

## JAVA

> System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

---

## PYTHON

> print driver.current_url