# How to know webDriver opened URL successfully

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

How to know WebDriver opened an URL successfully after `driver.get(appURL)`? I can see it opens nicely in a browser. But I would like to make sure programmatically.
Hey. Here I am asking whether driver.get(appURL) returns any response code like http response. Or I have to find a ID from the web page and find it, then make conclusion, but the approach seems too primitive. I am looking for more simple solution. Someone suggested assertTrue, but some reason Eclipse is giving long error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get url from selenium test class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091979/how-to-get-url-from-selenium-test-class-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do so, would be to assert over the page title of the url you have opened :

```
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
String expectedTitle = "YourExpectedPage"; // replace with the expected page title
org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(expectedTitle.equals(actualTitle));
```

Comment: @AndBatu its from `Junit` library `Assert.assertTrue`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can wait some time and check expected result then check current url

```
String currentURL = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='someID']")).isDisplayed()){ //add id or xpath
currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println(currentURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has a default error page. For chrome i am using:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='error-code']")).isDisplayed()){
MessageBox.Show("chrome error page.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with simple statements

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String baseUrl="https://stackoverflow.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(baseUrl.equals(driver.getCurrentUrl()))
    {
        System.out.println("URLS are matching");
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("URLS are not matching");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a `End User` we really don't have to be concerned about whether **`WebDriver`** instance opened an URL successfully or not because once the **`WebDriver`** instance requests for a `URL`, the Browser Client on opening the webpage/website (by default) returns **`document.readyState`** as **`complete`** to the **`WebDriver`** instance and only then our next line of code gets executed.

However, as an End User we can configure the **`WebDriver`** instance to act on different available states of the **`DOM`** as well. Currently Selenium recognizes **`document.readyState`** at 3 different stages as follows:

1. **`none`** - `The document is still loading`
2. **`eager`** - `The document is interactive`
3. **`normal`** - `The document is complete`

Hence our scripts can be written to configure the **`WebDriver`** instance to respond as per your requirement.